# Can't print from fluxbox unless I first log in to a different WM

Tags: linux-mint, printing, fluxbox

I'm running Linux Mint 17 with fluxbox as my WM. If I boot the machine and log in to a fluxbox session, I can't print; the printer doesn't show up in print dialogs. If I log in to a cinnamon session, then log out and log in to a fluxbox session, printing works. Clearly cinnamon is performing some initialization that causes the printer to be recognized by the OS. How can I get this initialization to happen in fluxbox?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what these *print dialogs* are? Name a few example-programs where the print dialog is not working as expected.

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин: For instance, if I print from Firefox, it pops up a dialog box that's meant to let me select the printer. There's normally supposed to be a list of printers in it. The list is empty in this condition. It's not just in one GUI program. I also get an error when I do an lpr from the command line: "lpr: Error - scheduler not responding."

Comment: Could the solution be simply [startinging the cups service](http://mint-my.blogspot.no/2012/08/editing-boot-up-service-in-linux-mint.html) which is responsible for all-things-printer?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I misunderstood what was happening. I think the cups service is just very slow to start. Logging in and out of a cinnamon shell was taking long enough that the service would finish starting up. If I boot, log in to a fluxbox, and do a "service cups start," it hangs for about 20 seconds before telling me the service has started. So I think the issues are (1) starting cups is slow, and (2) there is no good error reporting for the condition where it's still starting up. Maybe cinnamon users don't notice because cinnamon is slow to start.